# Convert a decimal degree to meters from the MySQL Spatial GLength

Tags: convert, spatial-database, mysql, units

The MySQL Spatial function GLength returns the distance between two points, this distance is  in the same unit from the projection. Since I'm using the WGS84 (SRID:4326) the answer will be with decimal degrees. But I need to convert this to meters.

Searching I got the answer to my question that there is a proportion of 111200 meters (others say 111111 or 111044) to 1 degree.

Checking with QGis ruler with the geometrys generate I got a different number to that proportion: 80321 meters/1 dd

Which one is right?

Comment: 111111 i think is good one. remember one degree is not constant. If you need more accurate calculation consider proper coordinate conversion

Comment: Neither is correct, because a decimal degree is not a unit of length. At any given location the length corresponding to a decimal degree varies with the bearing, too.  Please [search our site](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=convert%20meters%20degree) for many, many posts on this topic.  You need to project your data before making measurements.  That's covered by many tags, including [tag:projection-conversions].